# For anypair of $(x,y)$ is $x+y + xy$ always unique?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I was solving a computer science problem and was thinking of a way to encrypt an unordered pair of $(x,y)$ to a single value, I tried playing with bits a bit but did not get any conclusions But I think for any unordered pair of $(x,y)$ the Value of $x+y + xy$ is always unique for it, It is purely intuition-based, I am looking for a valid proof, If it is wrong Please present a counterexample for it.
For eg a pair of $(2,5)$ no other pair of numbers can give me the value $17$.
If anyone has any other way to encrypt two numbers Please suggest
The numbers are always Positive Numbers.

Comment: Depends what values $x,y$ are allowed to take. If they can only be positive integers, you may be right. If they are allowed to be any real numbers, this is obviously false.

Comment: they are only positive for my case , Can you give me a counter example when it fails for negative numbers?

Comment: (2,5) and (5,2) will yield same value.

Comment: pair is unordered

Comment: A real-valued function $f(x,y)$ will give some surface and $f(x,y)=z$ is some contour. $f$ will have to be more complicated than that to ensure it is 1-1.

Comment: If $x_1=x_2=-1$ then $y_1,y_2$ can be anything....

Comment: what is contour in your terms ?

Comment: @dmtri Only Positive numbers are possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$1 + 25 + 1\cdot 25 = 51 = 3 + 12 + 3\cdot 12$.

If you want an injective mapping from $\mathbb N^2$ to $\mathbb N$, then you could take any two prime numbers $p,q$ and define the mapping

$$(x,y)\mapsto p^x\cdot q^y$$

or, if you want something a little less explosive, take

$$(x, y) \mapsto 2^{x-1}\cdot (2y - 1)$$

This mapping is not only injective, it is *bi*jective, i.e. it hits *all* integers, and each one exactly once.

Comment: got it , Can you give me any other way to encypt a pair of numbers?

Comment: Thanks for explaining this new way both explosive and non explosive way of Encrypting a pair , Nicely explained

Comment: is it possible to generalise the non explosive ways for n-tuples?

Comment: @impopularGuy There exist a bijection from $\mathbb N^n$ to $\mathbb N$ for all values of $n$, but I am not sure if it can be quite as elegant. The 2-touple solution takes each number as a product of $2$ to some power and the "remainder" which is odd. I think it should be possible to do the same as a product of $2$ to some power, and $3$ to some power, and the remainder, however that remained must be undivisible by $6$, and that is harder to achieve in a nice equation.

Comment: @impopularGuy What I mean is that you would need a nice way of writing the mapping from $\mathbb N$ to the set of all numbers that are not divisible by $6$, and I can't think of one from the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the graph of $f(x,y) = x+y+xy$, you see that different pairs may result in the same value.

You say $f(2,5)=17$. Now let's fix $x=1$ and we will find the $y$- co0rdinate such that $f(1,y)=17$
$$f(1,y) = 1+y+1\cdot y=17 \implies y = 8$$
So, below is the **counter-example:**
$$f(2,5)=f(1,8)=17$$.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such an answer , Got it thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has mentioned this yet, an easy way to see that $x+y+xy$ is not unique is to factorize a similar expression:

$$x+y+xy = 1+x+y+xy-1=(x+1)(y+1)-1$$

So given that $(x+1)(y+1)$ is not prime for some $x,y$, we can always find another pair $x', y'$ such that $x+y+xy = x'+y'+x'y'$. The counterexamples discussed stem from $2\times26 = 4\times 13$ and $3\times 6 = 2\times 9$.

In general, we can rewrite for nonzero $w$:

$$ux+vy+wxy=\frac {uv}w+ux+vy+wxy-\frac{uv}w=\frac1w((u+y)(v + xw) - uv)$$

hence for integers $u,v,w$ the value of this expression cannot be unique to every pair.

Comment: was looking for something ike this thanks